# The page isn't redirecting properly - Web2py Admin

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web2py

When I visit `https://www.myapp.com`, the site works perfectly. I can visit every page without issue, including `https://www.myapp.com/admin`. After I enter my password on the admin screen and click submit, the page redirects to `https://www.myapp.com/admin/site` with the following error displayed: `The page isn't redirecting properly`.

/home/www-data/web2py/routes.py

```
routers = dict(
        BASE= dict(
            default_application = 'myapp',
            default_controller = 'default',
            default_function = 'index',
            functions = ['function1', 'function2', ...],
                   )
    )
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]

  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

/etc/apache2/sites-available/web2py.conf

Exactly as it shows in the documentation: http://www.web2py.com/books/default/chapter/34/13/deployment-recipes

What could be causing this to happen?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by switching from the parameter-based system to the pattern-based routes_in and routes_out solution. I defined the routes for each page, and then added admin routing with `$anything` to expose admin.

```
routes_in = (
  ('/', '/myapp/default/index'),
  ('/admin/$anything', '/admin/$anything'),
  ...
)
```